# Exception in transferring decimal values to a table

Tags: java, user-interface

I am a beginner in java programming and right now I am making a program about ordering system gui. Suppose that get the data from a table from a different class that contains the items and I used `mouseClicked` to get the desired data to certain JTextFields. The data inside the Price contains decimal values and I need it to be transferred to another table for sales history and yet somehow I cannot successfully run the program since an exception would happen saying that `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "500.00"`

Attached below is my code in transferring the data to the table

```
AddB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int price = Integer.parseInt(PTF.getText());
            int quan = Integer.parseInt(QTF.getText());
            
            String tottal = String.valueOf(price * quan);

            AmountTF.setText(tottal);
            
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)RecTable.getModel();
            model.addRow(new Object[] {QTF.getText(), PTF.getText(), 
                    BrandNTF.getText(), AmountTF.getText(), FNameTF.getText(), dateForm.format(obj)});
```

Comment: It seems to me, that you are parsing to an integer, but the source contains a decimal number...

Comment: What line does the exception happen? Are you trying to use `Integer.parseInt` to parse the text "500.00"?

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a float/double (500.00) into your text field and attempt to parse this as an integer. Use `Double.parseDouble()` or `Float.parseFloat()` instead.